# accessing value from array of objects returns undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Im trying to send user information as a api result in nodejs.after successfull login i will get this data.in that I have to send role and username as a result with token.

```
[ { _id: 5d9db3d9eb2e7c7708b2787a,
   username: 'akasthee',
   password: '12345',
   role: 'User',
   __v: 0 } ]
```

```
users.find({
        username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password
    }, (err, user) => { if (user.length == 1) {
            var token = jwt.sign({ userID: user._id, username: req.body.username }, 'user_authenticate', { expiresIn: '10d' });

            res.status(200).send({ token:token ,role : user.role});
        }});
```

but user.role returns undefined
I tried user.filter but it was returning undefined

Comment: Yeah I can print user result and above is the result

Comment: see my posted answer

Comment: You could use `findOne` in order to get a single item rather than an array.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for length `if (user.length == 1)` so then it should be array then your line of code should be

```
res.status(200).send({ token:token ,role : user[0].role});
```

Comment: console.log(user[0].role); returns undefined

Comment: @Karthi the above array u posted is your query result right?? Then it should print??Where r u printing console.log(user[0].role).

Comment: inside if condition

Comment: @Karthi Can you print `console.log(user)` inside if condition???

Comment: undefined is returning only to role.for user[0].username returns actual value'

Answer (score 0):

```
users.find({
    username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password
}, (err, user) => {
    if (user.length == 1) {
        var token = jwt.sign({ userID: user[0]._id, username: req.body.username }, 'user_authenticate', { expiresIn: '10d' });
        // in jwtSign changed the UserId
        console.log("user[0].role", user[0].role)

        res.status(200).send({ token: token, role: user[0].role });
        // in res changed the role

    }
});
```

Try this it will work.

Comment: can you console the user and check whether you are getting the role in the user data

Comment: yes its getting above result is shown using console.log(user);

Comment: can you attach the screenshoot of user console,